# My IF statement will only run one condition - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a new object to my parse database and basically if a user is uploading a document and a document already exists for the specific criteria, I want to delete the old and update with the new. Here is my code:

```
if object.objectId == nil {

     postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                         UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

          if let error = error {

             if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {
                                    self.displayAlert("Please choose an image and expiration date", message: errorString)
          }

          } else {

             print("Saved new object \(postImage)")
             print("Saved new object:\(self.expirationField.text)")

             self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

             self.expirationField.text = ""
             self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "addDocument.jpg")
         }
     }

 } else {

        object.deleteInBackground()

        postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
              (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

             self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

             if let error = error {

                if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {
                                    self.displayAlert("Please choose an image and expiration date", message: errorString)
             }

             } else {

                print("Saved new object \(postImage)")
                print("Deleted old object and added:\(self.expirationField.text)")

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                self.expirationField.text = ""
                self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "addDocument.jpg")
             }
        }
 }
```

So what ends up happening is that it never runs the first condition, but the app compiles fine. If in the simulator it matches the first condition it just has my activity indicator that runs forever and doesn't save to parse. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You have more than one set of `if` statements in your code.  You may want to point out which one exactly you're having problems with.

Comment: So i've actually simplified my code a little and am still getting no results for when the first condition exists:

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify that the condition you think is occurring is actually occurring?

Comment: So i've actually simplified my code a little and am still getting no results for when the first condition exists.

What I think is wrong is maybe I'm declaring my if statement wrong? I've debugged it and I am showing that I have no values in that object so the code should be running correctly. I've tried wording it like:

if object.objectId == nil {}
if object == nil {}             //This one returns error: PFObject cannot be nil
if object.objectId == "" {}
if object["objectId"] == nil {}

Etc.. None of these seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let error = error
```

In here you're setting the value of a variable, and that will only be true, regardless of what the variable is, even if the value of error coming from Parse is nil/null.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how else I can set this up?

Comment: If this answer helped you, you want to make it solved so it can help other people

Comment: This didn't seem to be the only problem. It has to do more with how I'm declaring my if statement I think. Here is what I have above:

I've debugged it and I am showing that I have no values in that object so the code should be running correctly. I've tried wording it like: if object.objectId == nil {} if object == nil {} //This one returns error: PFObject cannot be nil if object.objectId == "" {} if object["objectId"] == nil {} Etc.. None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using While as a loop than put an If statement inside of it.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you would do this?